# How can I incrementally create an array of types?

Tags: c++, arrays, metaprogramming, c++20, constexpr

```
template<typename ...Args>
class TypesArray {
    std::tuple<Args...> *tuple_;

    template<typename T>
    struct push_back_s {
        using type = TypesArray<Args..., T>;
    };


    TypesArray(const Args &... t) {

    }

public:

    template<typename T>
    using push_back = typename push_back_s<T>::type;
};
```

Using, for example, std::tuple in c++, is quite simple to create an "array of types", that is create a tuple with some types, which one can iterate using compile time loop, and so define a callback which is applied to each type which is part of template args of std::tuple. So supposing to have a type called

```
using Arr = TypesArray<int>;
```

I need that Arr, at a certain point, can be "updated" to, for example, to `TypesArray<int, double>`. Everything is known at compile time. However in c++ I can't doing something like this

```
using Arr = TypesArray<int>;
using Arr = Arr::push_back<double>;
```

but for example I could do this

```
using Arr = TypesArray<int>;
{
    using Arr = Arr::push_back<double>;
    {
        using Arr = Arr::push_back<float>;
        MyFunc<Arr>();
    }
}
```

How ever the visibilty of the inner Arr is limited at the inner block, so in that case I should use a template function inside the most inner block. However I should find for this solution a way to make generate to compiler an arbitrary depth of these recursive nested blocks and then (probably) pass to the last a function as termination step.
What I can't do is to define incrementally an array of types, ideally doing a thing like this:

```
using Arr = TypesArray<int>;
....
using Arr = Arr::push_back<double>;
...
using Arr = Arr::push_back<float>;
...
MyFunc<Arr>(); // MyFunc<TypesArray<int, double, float>>
```

I thought at a macro counter, but everything will be enclosed in a macro so I can't have a counter for exampled using boost preprocessor library, and the default  __COUNTER__  of gcc is not safe to use like a variable (it could be altered in other statements).

Comment: Why do you have to insist that the name of the type alias *must* be the same? This looks like an XY problem to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for stateful metaprogramming. See [unconstexpr](https://github.com/DaemonSnake/unconstexpr-cpp20/) for inspiration.

Example usage: <kbd>[run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAGwA7KSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEgCspAAOqAqETgwe3r4BwemZjgLhkTEs8YlcKXaYDtlCBEzEBLk%2BfkG2mPYlDE0tBGXRcQnJts2t7fldCpNDESOVYzUAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMwRyN5YANQm%2B27Ic%2BhYVBfYJhoAggdHJ5jnl16OtIQAng8nq8XgRMCxUgYwV83AR/qlGKxPgAVB6nObELwOU7NYDnQIWLyZIw4%2BGfC4AEVOqP2VkCFIuVhewOYbAUqSYO1O4TmwJMBOBpyFp1ZmHZnM%2BeAhtEFwv5TOewqVOPBkKY0IusLJotOUSRpHRBHQIBAmQAXpgAPoEU4ASQYWFUQJeyuFGKxNuw9BYACVMEwsMRZa75cHXXKzIcqKc7ot0BBLZaAOJRORuROrc5mfzmfynMBgWOReOJ46GYAZsPhrP7VLEJjAFhMU5JtxuGN4BsMDKOZCnVJEhBV8MHOsNpsttsdrs9vB9vDAbvETDoLNmAC0AHVuwx12DperMOuqMQ8K5zGZhyHI648PcXdXhSezw7TmgGHNMKo66cmD9UL%2B6C0JatoQjyBBeuCECQb6/qBpqepsAa9qOg8qyMleypvNGRYrgmyapumlqZrmub5oWmA0MW%2BFlkYlYPo%2BNZjo2zatu2%2BAznMc79qgqSYUqBy3veiojvSGHMgxyr7mqGqXHCCI6ohmAGjcJrmlaNooV%2BBryYibCnAAamIXiYM6Imuu62IwZup5gkGkkCQKDnhs%2BrhvgIn7fsQv7/oBwGgak4EwdB3p%2BgGCQIfqdoOl%2BaH8XKTnmYxwrLgQWwMDiDaakZ3imfsjwCmJtLxUK/IMs5pVFQqmHvp5P4AG6oHgq4Bv5YF4HMwUkYVVIAPS9aciroD4LD/INFKhJlxDAJgBAAHR8hVKoHrJWoKUiupRappp4Ba1rRY6OnahtcgMHgACOJlHet%2BmUqcjXNWZ1aWTabhiMgQi7Z8ICGsaIARGCwD1sBtXNIImrbep1rITFTr5fidIMsVElJUq0lQuScnHfpSkqUaalfftWmqNdemfKdF0mU94Yvacb20B9X2RUhB3aacFOXcpMb1LQukQA98atSB7Wdd6IXgmF8GXLjrNwwViOrIraI/fTjMWszXPE1mFinFwBoc1T8OhlVi2o8K6OHjCumKVt%2BM7Xtmmw6TOoG3ljxLUSER4pLMFfFS1sbVgxx80LAVBWLMGSxF0tRcTQI9YrJq6eJIJm0KFurRnmNrWTc152iAf6eBzsbTLhefLaJf6a71MWQQmLYj73rgQjZUp9WWdW6qGNW9jmB5wt8Pl9yHUEFXnwy5DhM2gPlekjd5NnZztfKrTTfguBmrF5tLPbREjqWkonMMDsmq2gPDz60vhvYAjnskrpfsj7ylzrywGvIVflNuxf%2BUYSbkk24oyVLTCklE/y81dq3ABqclT9Tpu9LwGMFA4gQJ8ZAWxlyCFOH8OY6IvoLUkp3TUw8y593ZtfTGVIwFUAgfIShK8Ih/EiO5D8YIvK/QJg7fBFon5SkhCaVWn11YxxZhoL%2By98omnqsZPK1VJLwORJsZACBUEdXnp8Igv5UgKVXCYfwGgcpUwMTiACBA0E4NHoQpKxCsYLx3lzYeRjHHkKgXdZxK9754mUIOCwnIADWfDpQmmsrZaObhJ5M1EVzGu%2BUDQeL/sjWBwp4F%2BjSsQD8qDNFkn7MueqTgiS0DGhyBQShVxaP0RoGyhBMADDBJUg0JA3x/iUCg5sQgABitoojPFvgkYgJBrFo27pbEh5DJ52yhppceFDv5PxoXQ2J7skpeNOL7O6/DaAmjfh/O0Eib4pzDLY2EIzM591/rfYe29SFRWHm4/Y1DwFIPod/TxxI8QwRQXdYemztlwRgpvS428Jl/SbP4q0%2B8vyH0wMfU%2Blx1K7KWZfWZkjsBJzJIcsSKM3gnw%2BDCJwGJ/Tvz/ijY5w8aTLIFqcZQp5BDIjJBAdCzJEoCUjHeO4pxLQAFkhDpgMtgH0YZtpoB%2BDCTUnLLQdLkFENwQhbRJkTGKy4%2BY9hJDcAwMAewkmsv2D0JQQq7YiptJqcViZlA%2BmwMiZEABNSV0q3DIltAAeSiIqk1yrNUmDVRqrVCodVCT5Fi1OANThNgiIywNfq3T1w9NSMkChnjEHrGNY2SMo1ChpQDelCIt6jxCd6BQEM7ZpUhFzbNYpE3JoNEHXmDKvVWCSAyBOQJ8oRtpKceB20S30HdcspU/MmroFWOBE0PiFAID8cgfxmpy0JqTUwf4BoAbx0Ru3YUma6UYqBXmkAnyi1/W7WW%2BNlaF3Vp5nzetXqm0KxbdgNtOtO3Fq8KWzUy6SVJQHc1YdO6x0ToCTO4987F0xk2LEHtf8eprozbSgg5bc1zHzeCQt8Kn2loNLOk9wGa0XqSA269ZV0KJLvYRh9A0u3PvA24AG1bQPgb7cKT9Q6R0gF/ZO6dlwMNAYNFQWgqB1Qrrbtq9dMG4PboQ7ugt%2B6k4UaPQiOdVbubBzrbhq9qbCOPFbSRjtZHUOUeoyBrwYGuY8b4wQMyZUODrC2RwJIvA/AcC0KQVAnA3DWGsOiTY2xySRh4KQAgmhLPrH8SASQABOOaoXAj7AAByhY0PsfYoXJBmCSEkUL%2BhOCSDswFpznBeAKBAOI/zDnLOkDgLAGAiAUCoAhHQBI5BKBoFq/QRItFgBSA0OImgvMEgFYgLEHLsQIgtH%2BJwXzTW2CCCdQwIpOWsBNiMOIErpB8DLgaPVMUOWvz1B%2BLsRzAMeg5b%2BLEesxB/geCwDl%2BuUoxulZ4w2BQBkzwAHcnUKVuzIQQIgxDsCkJ9%2BQSg1A5d0HrAwRgUBucsPoPAsQCuQHWLxPoBWODrhuJSUwlhrBmA0EKLcYhaCnC3F%2BeuzZ1wInQIYXs65%2BkkAUPlno9Q%2BguAdNMPweswiLAqFUPQRQsgCFZzzjIfOGDDC5ysbovRGjzAF3rOoDQBADFaKL0Y1QJiDBl2rpXnOVcSHWAoTzOw9D10wLsHgVnOC2dIPZxzzmOCqGi/4dc/hJBvjB3iKQc0NCe9OBAVzmOodrPwEQbyBw9Z0xq6kOrIefOrF4MVrQitSDBaSOI6zWXSAsBAGYMwc1otmCi5IZ3/gkjRa4P4ULZerc5dt/lwrfmAvrHK1VzYBABxjwoBAJrkeWtKU4Pbx3zvXfllOPsXPvAVyEBIM1PQ/AvuiHEH92fAOVDqGWyD0gz36ypFu%2Bbmz2Xlu26dT8NvpxUDRn707l3bXdaSE99733Eeo81i4LH%2BvJXE9oPCokRlGWODp8z4EIEHNFwIENmEkPsOAZIFwNFvsBoNFlXgfnlrYHXvHoFkniACnp7tmFwBoKFv4AYkkIEJIFAb/vsPvjbkgagYntZmYOQbwDXm/gnusBtsQJkM4JIEAA%3D%3D%3D)</kbd> (implementation is at the bottom of the answer)

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void PrintType()
{
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
    std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << '\n';
    #else
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    #endif
}

int main()
{
    struct TypesArray {};
    PrintType<List::Elems<std::tuple, TypesArray, decltype([]{})>>(); // std::tuple<>
    (void)List::PushBack<TypesArray, int>{};
    PrintType<List::Elems<std::tuple, TypesArray, decltype([]{})>>(); // std::tuple<int>
    (void)List::PushBack<TypesArray, double>{};
    PrintType<List::Elems<std::tuple, TypesArray, decltype([]{})>>(); // std::tuple<int, double>
    (void)List::PushBack<TypesArray, float>{};
    PrintType<List::Elems<std::tuple, TypesArray, decltype([]{})>>(); // std::tuple<int, double, float>
}
```

The big quirk here is that every list operation needs to be fed a unique type, because otherwise compilers tend to cache types and avoid updating them.

As you'll see below, my `PushBack` by default uses the inserted type for this (which automatically rejects duplicate types; if this is not what you want, pass a custom unique type), and for `Elems` I manually pass `decltype([]{})`, which yields a unique type every time.

You might be able to put `decltype([]{})` into a default template argument to avoid passing unique types manually, but last time I tried it, it didn't work reliably on all compilers, maybe things are better now.

Implementation:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

template <typename T> struct tag {using type = T;};

namespace List
{
    namespace impl
    {
        template <typename Name, std::size_t Index>
        struct ElemReader
        {
            #if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
            #pragma GCC diagnostic push
            #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wnon-template-friend"
            #endif
            friend constexpr auto adl_ImpListElem(ElemReader<Name, Index>);
            #if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
            #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
            #endif
        };

        template <typename Name, std::size_t Index, typename Value>
        struct ElemWriter
        {
            friend constexpr auto adl_ImpListElem(ElemReader<Name, Index>)
            {
                return tag<Value>{};
            }
        };

        constexpr void adl_ImpListElem() {} // A dummy ADL target.

        template <typename Name, std::size_t Index, typename Unique, typename = void>
        struct CalcSize : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Index> {};

        template <typename Name, std::size_t Index, typename Unique>
        struct CalcSize<Name, Index, Unique, decltype(void(adl_ImpListElem(ElemReader<Name, Index>{})))> : CalcSize<Name, Index + 1, Unique> {};

        template <typename Name, std::size_t Index, typename Unique>
        using ReadElem = typename decltype(adl_ImpListElem(ElemReader<Name, Index>{}))::type;

        template <template <typename...> typename List, typename Name, typename I, typename Unique>
        struct ReadElemList {};
        template <template <typename...> typename List, typename Name, std::size_t ...I, typename Unique>
        struct ReadElemList<List, Name, std::index_sequence<I...>, Unique> {using type = List<ReadElem<Name, I, Unique>...>;};
    }

    struct DefaultUnique {};

    // Calculates the current list size.
    template <typename Name, typename Unique = DefaultUnique>
    inline constexpr std::size_t size = impl::CalcSize<Name, 0, Unique>::value;

    // Touch this type to append `Value` to the list.
    template <typename Name, typename Value, typename Unique = Value>
    using PushBack = impl::ElemWriter<Name, size<Name, Unique>, Value>;

    // Returns the type previously passed to `WriteState`, or causes a SFINAE error.
    template <typename Name, std::size_t I, typename Unique = DefaultUnique>
    using Elem = impl::ReadElem<Name, I, Unique>;

    template <template <typename...> typename List, typename Name, typename Unique = DefaultUnique>
    using Elems = typename impl::ReadElemList<List, Name, std::make_index_sequence<size<Name, Unique>>, Unique>::type;
}
```

Comment: I see that this code works only with clang, how to compile this in gcc?

Comment: @Jhowa Try this version. Something is wrong with `requires`...